# How can I specify port number for the database in Web.config in MVC5?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an MVC5 app, which uses a MySQL database hosted in Azure. The point is that it works fine when I access it through CDBR endpoint, but I need to to connect to the database master, which uses the port 3310, unlike casual 3306 that CDBR uses. Is there anyway, where I can provide the port number for my database host?

Currently my connection strings looks something like this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Database=dbname;Data Source=hostname;User Id=username;Password=password" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the port in the connection string. Check [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) for your specific scenario.

```
User ID=root;Password=myPassword;Host=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myDataBase; Direct=true;Protocol=TCP;Compress=false;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0; Max Pool Size=100;Connection Lifetime=0;
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the link in your answer.

Comment: Edit your answer, don't put it in a comment.